Big space below a table that cannot be fixed by vspace
I work on a multicol document and when I am defining a table there is a huge space below it, around 7 lines of space. I tried \vspace with negative values but it doesnt work, only when I put extreme values the text and the table are overlapping, I tried \setlength\textfloatsep{\baselineskip} but it didnt worked. I also tried
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}  \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-10pt}

This worked but the caption of the figures was overlapping with the figures. I put a screenshot of the how the table is shown.

\documentclass{article}%%%%where cta-author is the template name


\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{}
\usepackage{multicol,caption}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}{}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}{}
\usepackage{amsmath} %for dealing with mathematics,
\usepackage{amsthm} %for dealing with theorem environments,
\usepackage{cite} %for dealing with citations
\usepackage{hyperref} %for linking the cross references
%\usepackage{graphics} %for dealing with figures.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithmic} %for describing algorithms
%\usepackage{subfig} %for getting the subfigures e.g., "Figure 1a and 1b" etc.
%\lipsum
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{Figure}
  {\par\medskip\noindent\minipage{\linewidth}}
  {\endminipage\par\medskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{skip=1pt}
\epstopdfsetup{update} % only regenerate pdf files when eps file is newer
%\newcommand*{\email}[1]{%
   % \normalsize\href{mailto:#1}{#1}\par
    %}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{*1}{*0.5}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{*0.5}{*0.3}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{*0.3}{*0.2}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\intextsep}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\floatsep}{1pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\setlength\textfloatsep{\baselineskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}



\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Model Performance Metrics}
\label{tab1}
\centering
\resizebox{0.48\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{} c c c c c @{}}
\hline
Metric & Model A & Model B & Model C & Model D\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluation using Dataset X} \\
\hline
Metric 1 & 95.00\% & 94.00\% & 93.50\% & 92.75\%\\
\hline
Metric 2 & 89.20\% & 88.40\% & 87.60\% & 86.80\%\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluation using Dataset Y} \\
\hline
Metric 1 & 91.35\% & 90.75\% & 90.20\% & 89.50\%\\
\hline
Metric 2 & 85.50\% & 84.90\% & 84.30\% & 83.70\%\\
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluation using Dataset Z} \\
\hline 
Metric 1 & 93.25\% & 92.50\% & 92.00\% & 91.50\%\\
\hline
Metric 2 & 88.10\% & 87.40\% & 86.70\% & 86.00\%\\
\hline 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{Evaluation using Custom Features} \\
\hline 
Metric 1 & 89.66\% & 88.90\% & 88.30\% & 87.75\%\\
\hline
Metric 2 & 83.29\% & 82.75\% & 82.25\% & 81.75\%\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}

For example, my document start like this
\begin{multicols}{2}

If I use the provided example which is shown below, the table disappears and I have to use \userpackage{float} and H
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{An Example of a Table}%%%Table caption goes here
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c}%%%The number of columns has to be defined here
\hline
Column heading & Column heading two & Column heading three\\ %%%% Table body
\hline
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 \\%%%% Table body
Row 1 & Row 2 & Row 3 \\%%%% Table body
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}%%%End of the table


Welcome! You discovered why [H] is bad.

Unfortunately if I dont use H the figures and tables are not shown for some reason..

Thats what I am saying, without H (using btp, h, h! or anything else)  the table disappears

Sorry, surely figures and tables are shown. Please, make a minimal example (using \lipsum) to show the issue. As it stands, the question cannot be answered.

I updated the question with a smaller example.

The problem is obviously with multicols. Why not using the twocolumn option instead?

Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols' environment!.

Specifically, look for the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/107497 that begins "do not use a floating environment if you do not want it float."
